# Searching for a way to slide small array inside larger array while checking neighbouring elements from the middle of the small array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, nearest-neighbor

What might be an approach I could take if i need to "slide" for example a,
3x3 array inside a larger array element by element and check if any of the x's 8 neighbouring elements contains "1"? I want to change the value of the middle if there is 1 in neighbouring values.
I'm finding it hard to explain the issue and haven't found similar questions on the site, so I hope it makes any sense.

```
slidingArr = 
{
 0, 0, 0
 0, x, 0
 0, 0, 0
}

arrToSlideOn =
{
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
}
```

Comment: Can you slide it anywhere on the big array? Or does it have to be only where there are zeros, ones etc?

Comment: Also, is the slidingArray always going to be 3x3 or can it vary in size?

Comment: I want it to slide through all the individual elements in the big array. The small sliding array can be of a varying size, as long as it is smaller than the big array and a square of uneven numbers. for ex. in this situation 3x3, 5x5, 7x7 would do.

Comment: Since what matters to you is actually the middle x number, you could just keep the x position. Start at 2nd row 2nd column and move one column to the right until you hit the penultimate column. Move down and then right until the penultimate column. Move down until you are at the penultimate row, penultimate column. At each iteration you check the numbers around it. Top left is BigArray[posX - 1][posY - 1], check that top left is 1, change inner number. Proceed to top middle all the way to bottom right.